# Not able to find template in Django Framework

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

As part of a project, I'm developing a social networking website. When I try to load a webpage, a django.template.exceptions error message appears. TemplateDoesNotExist. I have examined every setting, installed application, and template directory item in relation to their position. Everything was running smoothly without any issues up until yesterday. When I began working today, I started running across this issue. The location in the errors is exactly right, thus I don't understand how it can't locate the template. Additionally, I have four templates, of which two (the recently built ones) are experiencing this issue while the other two load without any issues.

([Images of Error I am facing right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8QLp.jpg))
[View.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGXUJ.jp) [Settings.py 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nCa3.jpg) [Settings.py 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXAK1.jpg)

I am trying to display a HTML file and expecting to come over on my browser.

Comment: post your **views.py** for futher help

Comment: And also post settings.py file

Comment: paste as code not as img

Comment: In your project root, which folder you created for html files. means template or templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your signup view, you made mistake while rendering template. You have added `signup` without html extension.

Instead of this:

```
return render(request,'signup')
```

Try this:

```
return render(request,'signup.html')
```

Comment: Thank you, it functions. Rendering requires an HTML page with only an extension, whereas redirecting does not, Is is correct?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: If it is helps you please accept the answer